# Check if values in one dataframe match values from another, updating dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have 2 dataframes,
both have different lengths but the same amount of columns

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Russia','Mexico','USA','Argentina','Denmark','Syngapore'], 
'population': [41,12,26,64,123,24]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Russia','Argentina','Australia','USA'], 
'population': [44,12,23,64]})
```

Lets assume that some of the data in `df1` is outdated and I've received a new dataframe that contains some new data but not which may or may not exist already in the outdated dataframe.

I want to find out if any of the values of `df2.country` are inside `df1.country`

By doing the following I'm able to return a boolean:

```
df = df1.country.isin(df2.country)

print(df)
```

Unfortunately I'm just creating a new dataframe containing the answer to my question

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: country, dtype: bool
```

My goal here is to delete the rows of `df1` which values match with `df2` and add the new data, kind of like an update.

I've manage to come up with something like this:

```
df = df1.country.isin(df2.country)
i = 0
for x in df:
    if x:
        df1.drop(i, inplace=True)
    i += 1
frames = [df1, df2]
df1 = pd.concat(frames)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

which in fact works and updates the dataframe

```
     country  population
0     Mexico          12
1    Denmark         123
2  Syngapore          24
3     Russia          44
4  Argentina          12
5  Australia          23
6        USA          64
```

But I really believe there's a batter way of doing the same thing quicker and much more practical considering that the real dataframe is much bigger and updates every few seconds.

I'd love to hear some suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: Is `col1` kind of like a unique key?

Comment: ``col1`` is the column in the dataframe which contains the name of the item that needs to be updated

Comment: That should mean `a`, will only occur once in your outdated dataframe right?

Comment: That's correct, ``a`` can be anything from city name to animals and all other columns may be population to number of legs, whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) approach is so close! Simply use the results from `isin` as a mask, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the rows from `df1` that are not in (`~`) `df2` with the rest of `df2`:

```
m = df1['country'].isin(df2['country'])
df3 = pd.concat((df1[~m], df2), ignore_index=True)
```

`df3`:

```
     country  population
0     Mexico          12
1    Denmark         123
2  Syngapore          24
3     Russia          44
4  Argentina          12
5  Australia          23
6        USA          64
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `col1` remains unique in the original dataframe, you can join the two tables together. Once you have them in the same dataframe, you can apply your logic i.e. update value from new dataframe if it is not null. You actually don't need to check if `col2` has changed for every entry in `col1`. You can just replace `col2` value with `col1` as long as it is not `NaN` (based on your sample output).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','f','r','g','d','s'], 'col2': [41,12,26,64,123,24]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','g','o','r'], 'col2': [44,12,23,64]})

# do the join
x= pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer', 
               left_on="col1", right_on="col1")


col1    col2_x  col2_y
0   a   41.0    44.0
1   f   12.0    NaN
2   r   26.0    64.0
3   g   64.0    12.0
4   d   123.0   NaN
5   s   24.0    NaN
6   o   NaN 23.0


# apply your update rules
x['col2_x'] = np.where(
                  ~x['col2_y'].isnull(),
                  x['col2_y'],x['col2_x']
                  )

    col1    col2_x  col2_y
0   a   44.0    44.0
1   f   12.0    NaN
2   r   64.0    64.0
3   g   12.0    12.0
4   d   123.0   NaN
5   s   24.0    NaN
6   o   23.0    23.0

#clean up
x.drop("col2_y", axis=1, inplace = True)
x.columns = ["col1", "col2"]


    col1    col2
0   a   44.0
1   f   12.0
2   r   64.0
3   g   12.0
4   d   123.0
5   s   24.0
6   o   23.0
```

Comment: Thanks! it might work but I think with big amounts of data it's quicker to first evaluate if any reshaping is required instead of reshaping everything and than evaluating